# early returns in functional components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Will it be a good practice to have an early return in a functional component using hooks. for example

```
const dummyComponent =({name}) => {

   if(!name){
     return;
  }

useEffect(()=>{ console.log("name changed");},[name])


const handler =(event)=>{
  console.log("handler called");
}

return(
<div onClick={handler}> Click Me!!!</div>
)}

}
```

the above code will lead to change in the flow of useeffect calls.
initially if the name is defined in parent and passed to the child it will execute but in case the name changes in parent and becomes undefined the flow of useeffect changes.

Will this be a good practice to have an early return ?

Comment: You'd be way better off with [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) of your component within parent and simply skip rendering it if variable to be passed as a prop to a child is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll have to return some sort of JSX from the component. The early return doesn't help you a lot in this case as the hook will be called only when the name prop changes. The way you have defined your example now can be a cause of memory leaks. The more preferred approach is doing a conditional render like this

```js
{name ? <div onClick={handler}> Click Me!!!</div> : <div />}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the memory leaks part.? Also, does it mean we should avoid early return in functional components?

Comment: So, first of all, when you return early from a function you violate the rules of hooks as their order is not maintained. This is one place where there are chances of memory leaks. You can return early from a functional component if it does not have any kind of internal state. In all other cases, conditional rendering is the preferred approach.